# Positioning foregroundwindow with c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

So I'm working on my C++ file, I'm using the Windows library to set my current window to the top left corner, it kind of works but is 14px away from the left. I wonder how you fix that, tried to set the x coordinate to -14, but nothing changed. I'm really bad at C++ and that's why I'm here. I kind of know why it doesn't work, but I only know it can be solved in Windows 10 and not Windows 11.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

int main() {
    Rect desktopRect;

    GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(), &desktopRect);
    HWND hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
    if (hwnd != nullptr) {
        wchar_t title[MAX_PATH];
        GetWindowText(hwnd, title, MAX_PATH);
        std::wstring windowTitle(title);
        std::wcout << L"Window title: " << windowTitle << std::endl;
    }
    SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, 0, 0, sizex, sizey, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);

    return 0;
```

I tried and have been asking lots of people from communities and other friends for help. No one knows how. But nothing seems to work. Should I use a different library, or are there some workarounds? Btw I have Windows 11, some people have found the solution in Windows 10 but doesn't seem to work for me.

I am new here so my way of formulating the question might not be the best but I will learn and improve. All help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Is your program built to be DPI aware?

Comment: Windows have a hidden "shadow" border which makes them bigger than they appear. You can get the size of the shadow border using `DwmGetWindowAttribute` with `DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS`; one complication is that this won't return a valid value until after the window has been displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had success using [`DwmGetWindowAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmgetwindowattribute) with [`DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/ne-dwmapi-dwmwindowattribute) which retrieves the extended frame bounds rectangle in screen space. I used that to adjust the Window's position after having first tried to set it to the top left corner.

- Note: You need to link with `Dwmapi.lib`.

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <dwmapi.h>

#include <iostream>

constexpr LONG magic_constant = 1; // Don't know where it comes from

std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& os, const RECT& r) {
    return os << L'{' << r.left << L',' << r.top << L' '
              << r.right << L',' << r.bottom << L'}';
}

int main() {
    HWND hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
    if (!hwnd) return 1;

    // Try top left
    SetWindowPos(hwnd, nullptr, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
        
    // Get the DWM Window attribute DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS which
    // includes the offset from the border:
    RECT rect;
    HRESULT hRes = DwmGetWindowAttribute(hwnd, DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS,
                                         &rect, sizeof rect);       
    if (hRes == S_OK) {
        std::wcout << L"Current: " << rect << L'\n';

        // Set the position again, negating the offset:
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, nullptr, -rect.left - magic_constant,
                     -rect.top - magic_constant, 0, 0,
                     SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);

        // Check where we are:
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect);
        std::wcout << L"Result:  " << rect << L'\n';
    }    
}
```

Comment: It's better, but still 1 pixel off.

Comment: @Benjamin Ha! Annoying :-) What if you make it `-rect.left - 1, -rect.top`, does that do it?

Comment: I didn't actually test it, because it says file can't be found for some reason which is weird. But a guy in a community I'm in tested it and said it was 1 pixel off. Idk

Comment: @Benjamin I just inspected it more closely myself by taking a screenshot and blowing it up in GIMP and, yes, it's +1 on both the x and y axis. I'll adjust my answer although it's annoying to not know where that +1 comes from.

Comment: @Benjamin Great! It would be even greater if someone with deeper knowledge about the inner workings of the WinAPI could explain the `magic_constant` I added. Perhaps it shouldn't be a constant, but instead something that can be fetched by another WinAPI call.